# Basic user authentication and server hits

Tags: database, security, authentication, server

I have an app and each request must be authenticated. The app uses lots of server actions so there are many calls. So if I understand correctly, to make this app secure, I must send the user/session token with each request, and each time it will be authenticated against the database?

I am new to making back-end security, so is this the correct way? Are there ways to make such app less strenuous on the DB? Security is very important so I'll pay the extra load price if required...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very common way. When the token/session is sent on each request and checked it's validity against the DB.

The token/session "validation" should be DB read operation not write(exception session touching), so it is pretty easy to scale up and it is fast on relational databases.

If it makes too much load to your DB you can always build an cache between API and DB or use stateless sessions.

Second option is to sign/encrypt/hash the token/session with key and put some useful data inside it, like session/tokens expiry time, userId, accountId, permissions etc... This way you can give to the client some freedom and it can use the token/session as long it isn't expired. And you can validate it on application level no need to DB query.

There are lots of ways to do this, but always have to look at the needed performace and security requirements.

[good discussion](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49145/avoid-hitting-db-to-authenticate-a-user-on-every-request-in-stateless-web-app-ar)

Answer (score 1):

If you have your authentication service issue tokens that are signed, you do not need a round trip to the database to verify the token. If the token has not expired and is signed by a trusted issuer, you know who the caller is and can authorize the call.

The other advantage is that these token are session-less. No state is kept at the server, making your architecture scale better.

Comment: What are signed tokens?

Comment: Signed tokens are documents (XML or JSON typically) that carry a digital signature. See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature